# dyld: Symbol not found: __ZTISt9exception

Tags: ios6, crash, ios7, xcode5, symbols

I've deployed my application on iOS 7 and iOS6 device using xcode5.0. When I run on iOS6 and my application crashes. When I get the crash log, I've the following error :

Dyld Error Message:

```
dyld: Symbol not found: __ZTISt9exception
  Referenced from: /var/mobile/Applications/86566E4B-B2E1-4691-BF65-2AE486EF247F/Sample.app/Sample
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
  in /var/mobile/Applications/86566E4B-B2E1-4691-BF65-2AE486EF247F/Sample.app/Sample
```

But I've successfully run on iOS7.
How can I solve this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Change Deployment Target 7 into 6.1